# Determining MPI implementation programmatically

Tags: mpi, implementation, openmpi, mpich

Say that `/path/to/mpi/bin` is in my `PATH`. I can then invoke e.g. `mpicc` and `mpiexec`. If I now want to *programmatically* determine which MPI implementation I am dealing with (e.g. OpenMPI, MPICH), how could I do this?

The solution I got so far is to `grep` for some more og less arbitrary string in the output of e.g. `mpiexec --version`.

Specifically I need to distinguish between OpenMPI and MPICH, but a general solution would of course be nice.

Comment: If you need that information at compile/build/configure time, just try to compile a small example that uses the value of the `OPEN_MPI` preprocessor symbol. It is defined in `mpi.h` as `1` when `mpicc` comes from Open MPI. It will throw an error when compiling with MPICH.

Comment: An (unreliable) way to distinguish between the two at runtime is to, e.g., check the values of `MPI_INFO_NULL` and `MPI_INFO_ENV`. Both are compile-time constants with MPICH and runtime constants with Open MPI. The probability that both values could match randomly, especially given that MPICH defines `MPI_INFO_ENV` to be odd and Open MPI's null info object is likely aligned in memory, is really low (though non zero). But Open MPI code won't run properly under MPICH's `mpiexec` and vice versa, so that is probably less of a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [MPI_Get_library_version](https://www.citutor.org/SITES/AContent/home/course/content.php?_cid=72)